Custom Font in CSS
This is my first time attempting to use a custom font using CSS. I can't figure out why my linked font is not appearing in the navigation bar of webpage.  I am sorry if this seems like a dumb question although I am completely new to all of this and I am trying to revamp my website for FBLA Nationals at the end of the month. I will probably will have several more questions so if there is someone that is experienced and willing to communicate back and forth with me I would greatly appreciate it.
I have made sure the file path is right, in VSC it follows the link so I know that part is good.
this is my CSS:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Font1';
    src: url(Fonts/Font1.ttf) format('truetype');
  }
  
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f1c65a;
    font-family: 'Font1', sans-serif; /* Include fallback font */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  nav {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2; /* Ensure nav stays above other elements */
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Font1', sans-serif; /* Include fallback font */
  }
  
  nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  
  nav .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  nav .main-nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  
  nav a {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #023020;
  }
  
  nav a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
  
  .logo-container {
    width: 220px; /* Set the width of the logo container */
    height: auto; /* Allow the height to adjust proportionally */
  }
  
  .logo-container img {
    max-width: 100%; /* Make sure the logo doesn't exceed the container width */
    height: auto; /* Allow the height to adjust proportionally */
    margin-top: 135px;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure sidebar stays above other elements */
  }
  
  .sidebar li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .sidebar a {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 30px;
  }
  
  .menu-button {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-button ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .menu-button li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .menu-button a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #023020;
    height: 50px;
  }
  
  .menu-button a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
  
  footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 40px); /* Subtract the total padding from the width */
    left: 49%; /* Position the footer to the center horizontally */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Center the footer precisely */
    background-color: #f1c65a;
    color: #023020;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .footer-item {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #023020;
  }
  
  footer a:hover {
    background-color: #7B3F00;
    color: #023020;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    .hideOnMobile {
      display: none !important;
    }
  
    .menu-button {
      display: block;
    }
  
    nav .main-nav {
      justify-content: center; /* Align items to the right */
    }
  
    .logo-container img {
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-left: 80px; /* Push the logo to the right */
      width: 120px; /* Set the width of the logo container */
      height: auto; /* Allow the height to adjust proportionally */
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 400px) {
    .sidebar {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  


Couple of suggestions to debug the issue :
Check if the issue occurs persists in different browsers , sometimes the issue can also be related browser compatibility. Check  network requests and see if the font file is being loaded successfully.

Also I would be happy to help you!

@RavinaSarda have tried opening my index file on both Google Chrome and Opera GX and neither load my font. How do I do the network request thing? and do you have a way I can reach you more easily, I am not sure if this site has DMs or anything

Open Developer tools , inside that you can find a tab Network. Select All. You can see which all resources are loaded by the browser and status of them.
Also , If you can provide your email address , I can reach out to you

@RavinaSarda my font file is not shown under network only, my logo, CSS, and HTML. my email is gavin_knotts@outlook.com

As the file is not loaded , so this is the root cause why the font is not getting applied.

@RavinaSarda so how do I fix that

@Gavin_knotts are you on microsoft teams / Google meet / skype ? We can connect there

@RavinaSarda I am on teams, same email or if you prefer google datdude365d@gmail.com

For starters , you can check if the file path is correct  and Clear the cache. As long as the file is not loaded , the issue will persist. Also , just for debugging purpose , try adding a different font and check if everything works fine

Your CSS file is looking for the font file inside a /Fonts/ folder that is in the same folder as the CSS file. Is that where the /Fonts/ folder is actually located?

@ralph.m yes inside of my CSS folder is a Fonts folder

"and do you have a way I can reach you more easily, I am not sure if this site has DMs or anything" - it doesn't. Please keep the discussion of the problem here, instead of trying to solicit "private support" from individual site members.
